# Interpolated string not updated properly in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

So I have an Angular component:

```
<!-- login.component.html -->

...
<!-- switch between login and register mode -->
<a (click)="onToggleLoginRegister()">
    {{ isLogin ? 'Register now' : 'Log in with my account' }}
</a>
...
<!-- button for action -->
<button (click)="onClickLoginRegister()">{{ submitButtonText }}</button>
```

```
// login.component.ts

// ...
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked {

    // ...

    isLogin: boolean = true;
    submitButtonText: string = "";

    ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
        this.submitButtonText = 'Login';
    }

    onToggleLoginRegister() {
        this.isLogin = !this.isLogin;
        this.submitButtonText = this.isLogin ? 'Login' : 'Register';
    }

    onClickLoginRegister() { ... }
}
```

Basically the `<a>` acts as a switch between login and register mode. When I click it, the texts in both `<a>` and `<button>` should change accordingly. However, only the text in `<a>` gets updated, and the `<button>` text is always stuck to the initial value assigned in `ngAfterViewChecked()`. And I don't know why.

*(The reason why I design like this is that I need the button to show different texts in other cases)*

I tried to use a `ChangeDetecterRef` to force the change detection just like many posts said, but it didn't work.

However, when I swap the two lines in `onToggleLoginRegister()`, i.e. update `submitButtonText` before `isLogin`, both texts will get updated (not as expected though). But in other cases, I would like to solely update the `submitButtonText`, which is unlikely to work.

So I'm wondering if the difference in behavior is caused by the difference in data types (since the `<a>` is bound to a boolean and the `<button>` is bound to a string). And what would be the solution to this?

Comment: do you want to use the ngAfterViewInit instead ngAfterViewChecked? BTW, you can also declare your variable as `submitButtonText: string = "Login";`

Comment: @Eliseo well the code here is simplified and in my actual case the button text must be assigned after the view is checked, otherwise it won't display correctly.

Comment: @Eliseo I probably misunderstood these ng hooks. The ngAfterViewChecked is executed every time the interpolates get updated and set submitButtonText back to login. And the problem is now fixed in my actual code. I think I will delete this post later.

Answer (score 0):

Your ternary expression is backwards because you've just reversed the boolean isLogin before calling it.

```
        this.submitButtonText = this.isLogin ? 'Login' : 'Register';
```

should be

```
        this.submitButtonText = this.isLogin ? 'Register' : 'Login';
```

Comment: I believe the `submitButtonText` should correspond to the mode (login or register), which is defined by `isLogin`. I've edited the question to improve clarity.